# command not found in terminal of mac

Tags: macos, terminal, command, zsh

when I open terminal, it is suddenly showing

```
/Users/mine/.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/mine/.rvm/scripts/rvm:29: command not found: ps
```

and then I tried to run `flutter devices` or anything else like `git status` and it says `zsh: command not found: flutter`
is there a way to solve it?

[EDIT]

```
Last login: Mon Feb  1 09:43:50 on ttys000
/Users/umsi06/.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/umsi06/.rvm/scripts/rvm:29: command not found: ps
umsi06@umsi06s-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls
zsh: command not found: ls
umsi06@umsi06s-MacBook-Pro ~ % PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
umsi06@umsi06s-MacBook-Pro ~ % export PATH
umsi06@umsi06s-MacBook-Pro ~ % exec /bin/zsh
umsi06@umsi06s-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls
zsh: command not found: ls
umsi06@umsi06s-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

[2nd EDIT]

```
+/Users/umsi06/.zshrc:1> export PATH=/Users/umsi06/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/umsi06/Documents/platform-tools:/Users/umsi06/Downloads/flutter/bin
+/Users/umsi06/.zshrc:5> export PATH=/Users/umsi06/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/umsi06/Documents/platform-tools:/Users/umsi06/Downloads/flutter/bin:/Users/umsi06/.rvm/bin
+/Users/umsi06/.zshrc:6> export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/umsi06/Library/Android/sdk
+/Users/umsi06/.zshrc:7> export PATH=/Users/umsi06/Documents/platform-tools
+/Users/umsi06/.zshrc:8> export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/umsi06/Library/Android/sdk
+update_terminal_cwd:5> local url_path=''                                       
+update_terminal_cwd:9> local i ch hexch LC_CTYPE=C LC_ALL=''
+update_terminal_cwd:10> i = 1
```

Comment: Does this happen every time you open a Terminal window? If so, one or more of your zsh initialization scripts has gotten messed up, and you'll have to troubleshoot them. Have you made any changes (such as installing something new) recently?

Comment: yeaah I was doing installation yesterday, and when I open terminal today, I can not access anything, do you have idea how to solve this

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have edited my question, would you like to take a look

Comment: Try `exec /bin/zsh -x` to trace what the init files are doing, and look for `+ PATH=something` or `+ export PATH=something` in the output.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I found it.. I have edited my question, would you like to guide me for the next step

Comment: Looks like the problem is in line 7 of your .zshrc file. I'm not sure if it's intended to add `/Users/umsi06/Documents/platform-tools` to your `PATH`, but that's already there, and the problem is it's *removing* everything else from your `PATH`. So I think that line can just be deleted.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Maybe `zsh -x -l` would be better; the error could come from one of the files sourced by a login shell.

Comment: @uyhaW : According to what you posted, you included `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` into your PATH, but still `ls` is not found, which is supposed to be there. You can use `echo` (an internal command, no PATH needed) to investigate those directories. Do a `echo /bin/*` to see what files you have there.

Comment: GordonDavisson and user1934428 thank you very much for the help... this happens because I messed up the path after doing an installation and I ask my friend to help me and finally it is solved

Comment: thank you very much guys for the discussion, it helps me so much

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you mess up your PATH variable. (Your current PATH doesn't contain any location where common utilities are located hence all the commands are not .)

You can try:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Another way is that you can "reset" zsh, specify the complete path to the shell:

```
exec /bin/zsh
```

or

```
exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Hi, I try your answer step by step and then I try to access ```ls``` but I still get ```zsh: command not found: ls``` do you have any idea how to sole this?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question, would you like to take a look

Comment: hmm, can u try to `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I have tried it, and after ```export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH``` should I try ```PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH``` ?